# PHP cant connect to postgreSQL in ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, ubuntu, database-connection

I am trying to connect to a postgreSQL db with the following code.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    $dbh = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=southpark;host=localhost', 'jaseem' , 'DBPassword');
    var_dump( $dbh );
?>
```

It quits with an error message `object(PDO)#1 (0) { }`

How do i solve this issue ? Where did i go wrong ? Apache ? postgreSQL ? or php ?

Comment: `object(PDO)#1 (0) { }` is NOT an error message, it's effectively a visual representation of a PDO object by var_dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error - you're getting a PDO object. If the PDO instantiation failed, it'd thrown an error and not do the var_dump. If there was some other error, you can check `$dbh->errorCode()` and `$dbh->errorInfo()` for details.

Comment: So.. there's no error, you've got a PDO object as expected. Try to run a query.

Comment: @jaseem: then, how can you tell it does not work as expected ? All signs seem to indicate you are actually connected to postgre.

Comment: `resource(2) of type (pgsql link persistent)` on 'pg_pconnect("host=$global_host port=$global_port dbname=$global_dbname user=$global_user password=$global_password");'

Comment: Yes, that's expected. Your PDO connection is working. So what exactly is your problem?  because as things stand right now, your code is working exactly as it should be.

Comment: But im not getiing data out of it ! how can i get the output of 'select * from users' ?

Comment: umm.... `$result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users");`? You do have to issue a query to actually get data. Just connecting to a database in PHP doesn' tmagically turn your browser into Microsoft Access or similar.

Comment: i dont know about 'Microsoft Access', so how to i print the result ? I loved javascript and relative to that, php is shit ! this thing is not flexible at all ! How to print everything in $result ?

Comment: You should learn php before you start bashing it: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: okey ! PDO worked ! Now why the heck is `pg_connect` not working ?